# Find a DocumentObject in mongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongo db. Can any one know how to query to get the Document in mongo DB.

POJO class:

```
@Document(collection = "test")
public class Test implements  Serializable {

    @Field("source")
    private String source = null;
    @Field("content")
    private Content content = null;
    @Field("systemTime")
    private long systemTime;
}


@Document
public class Content  implements Serializable {
    @Field("id")
    private String tweetId = null;
    @Field("parentContentId")
    private String parentContentId = null;
}
```

Service Class:

```
public ServiceClass {

 public void hello{
 Test savedPayload = repository.save(test);
 String parentContentId = test.getContent().getParentContentId();

    if (parentContentId != null) {
        Test payLoadFound = (Test) repository.findByContent(parentContentId);

       }
    }
}

 public interface Repository extends
    MongoRepository<Test, Serializable> {
   List<Test> findByCIPContent(
           String parentContentId);
}
```

When I try to find the Test with content parentContentId  I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property c found for type CIPPayload!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:52) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:128) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210) ~[spring-data-commons-1.8.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer, it should be `findByContentParentContentId(parentContentId)`